# Authenticate rest api generated by hypperledger composer using passport-jwt

Tags: hyperledger-composer, passport-jwt

I want to authenticate my rest end points generated by composer rest server using passport-jwt. I have user database in mysql. Now, I want to allow access to only those users who are already registered. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Edited answer:There is a tutorial done by someone in the Composer community -> https://www.codementor.io/gangachris125/passport-jwt-authentication-for-hyperledger-composer-rest-server-jqfgkoljn . Also see this comment on retrieving the access_token cookie https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/2038#issuecomment-400696304 . Finally, for an example of an app using the passport-jwt strategy - see resources https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/learn-using-jwt-with-passport-authentication-9761539c4314 and Composer info in comments shown https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/2038 on JWT specifically. You use that jwt token to authenticate against the REST server and receive the accessToken cookie for all future REST server requests.

Comment: I have already implemented the steps mentioned in the github link provided by you, but yet I am not clear about where to write my custom logic to generate token and where the token will be generated in passport-jwt. Exact steps to follow will be highly appreciated.